# Automatically download android offline speech recognition language

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have developed an app based on speech to text (speech recognition) for Android 4.4 I know that I can manually download offline speech recognition languages by going into: Settings -> Language & input -> Google voice typing -> Offline speech recognition -> All.
I want to know Is there a way to install a offline speech recognition language automatically or by some programming tricks?

best regards.

Comment: Same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950791/embed-language-pack-with-application