# Embed language pack with application

Tags: android, voice-recognition, language-packs

I'm making an application which use offline voice recognition (SpeechRecognizer from the Google API). It works perfectly but I need to download the language pack before using the application. So, here is my question: Is there any way to embed the language pack and install it directly from my application?

Or can the language pack be downloaded with the application when it is downloaded from the Play store?

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835847/automatically-download-android-tts-engine